# Monotone class definition

Tags: monotone-class-theorem

I've been presented with a definition of monotone classes that I was unfamiliar with : a subset of the power set containing the entire space, closed under countable increasing union and difference between two ordered subsets.
I would have thought that it was equivalent to the other definition saying that it was closed under countable monotone unions and intersections.
I can't manage to prove it.... is it true ?
Thx

Comment: No, because this structure has complements, as well.

Comment: Is this other definition widespread ?